# Combinatorics in Python; individual values for the numbers the user puts in

Tags: python, calculator, combinatorics

I'm trying to make a combinatorics calculator in Python, and I don't necessarily want to limit the number of user inputs. I was wondering if I could make Python add individual values by itself. It's hard to describe what exactly I'm trying to do, but I'll explain any questions that may arise.

Answer (score 0):

The main point is noting that the combinations of length n from a set of length q  if the user has entered m numberss are the combinations of length n-m from the set with the set with the m input members removed.  Get the user input, check the user input, get new user input, get the input set and the set of remaining elements (use of the set operations will save some ugly loops) and find the needed combinations.